# HLS video become corrupted if using FFmpeg to download it

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I was trying to download an HLS video (.m3u8) using FFmpeg. The video was fine when I open the .m3u8 file directly VLC, but the .mp4 file downloaded using FFmpeg was totally broken (the frames and sound were missing every other second).

There're some warnings printed to the terminal while downloading:

- ```
  [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55df899ad5c0] DTS 0 < 22523 out of order
  ```
- ```
  [mp4 @ 0x55dafef205c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: <timecode>, current: <timecode>; changing to <timecode>. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
  ```

How can I do to fix the issue? I can provide more information if needed.

### Update (2020-10-12T23:10:00+08:00):

[Here](https://pastebin.com/uZ8KA9jX)'s the full log of FFmpeg.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan I've added the log of FFmpeg.